# How to return a decrypted password from the DB in Rails using Sorcery gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, encryption, sorcery

I've started using Sorcery for authentication purposes and have been wondering if there's a way to return a decrypted password from the DB ? When trying to return a password Rails returns **nil**. Is that even connected to the Sorcery gem or is it a Rails thing ? The other attributes work fine, e.g. the E-mail adress can be retrieved but not the password.

Any advice ? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Sorcery build with a `bcrypt` gem and the password hashing algorithm used by `OpenBSD`. You can't get the plain password from a column of your model, you can only compare a string and the encrypted hash with [`valid_password?`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/sorcery/Sorcery%2FModel%2FInstanceMethods%3Avalid_password%3F).

> `valid_password?` Calls the configured encryption provider to compare the supplied
>   password with the encrypted one.

Example how `bcrypt` work:

```
require 'bcrypt'

my_password = BCrypt::Password.create("my password") #=> "$2a$10$vI8aWBnW3fID.ZQ4/zo1G.q1lRps.9cGLcZEiGDMVr5yUP1KUOYTa"

my_password.version              #=> "2a"
my_password.cost                 #=> 10
my_password == "my password"     #=> true
my_password == "not my password" #=> false

my_password = BCrypt::Password.new("$2a$10$vI8aWBnW3fID.ZQ4/zo1G.q1lRps.9cGLcZEiGDMVr5yUP1KUOYTa")
my_password == "my password"     #=> true
my_password == "not my password" #=> false
```

I'm not a  `sorcery` user. Correct me if i'm a wrong.

Comment: Yeah I completely forgot that it uses bcrypt.. This seems pretty useful, I think I'll manage to make something out of this.  I'll post my findings later on :)